# how to get attribute value for soapui response using groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

my soap response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetInventoriesResponse xmlns="http://xxx">
         <GetInventoriesResult>
            <NewDataSet xmlns="">
               <Inventory attr1="1" attr2="101" />
               <Inventory attr1="1" attr2="101" />
            </NewDataSet>
         </GetInventoriesResult>
      </GetInventoriesResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I would like to read the values of attr1 from //Inventory[0]

What I am doing is

```
import groovy.sql.Sql  
import java.sql.DriverManager  
import java.sql.Connection  
import javax.sql.DataSource  
import java.sql.Driver;  
import java.util.*;  
import java.text.*; 

def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )  
def responseHolder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( messageExchange.responseContent )

responseHolder.namespaces['ns4']='http://xxx'

def CounGetInventoriesResponse=responseHolder["count(//Inventory)"]
def CompanyId=responseHolder.getNodeValue("//namf:Inventory[0]/@attr1")

log.info "att1"+CompanyId
```

value of companyid is displayed as null

How do I resolve this . What is missing here

Comment: i don't see `CompanyId` attribute in your xml

Comment: your question is about `xpath`. nothing wrong with your groovy code. better to remove `groovy` tag and add `xml` and `xpath` tags - this way you could get more answers on your real issue.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp

check predicates section in this article

`Inventory[1]` is a right way to reference first element

another issue - you are trying to access `Inventory` element with a namespace `"//namf:Inventory` when default namespace was reset to empty on the level of `NewDataSet` element: `<NewDataSet xmlns="">`

So, this should work

```
responseHolder.getNodeValue("//Inventory[1]/@attr1")
```